# Getting Timeout error while executing Code for Chat application

Tags: android, xampp, chat

I am trying to implement chat application in android I am getting timeout error.

Following is my code,

```
    public void connect() {

  dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
            "Connecting...", "Please wait...", false);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Create a connection
            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            try {
                connection.connect();
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                        "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                        + connection.getHost());
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                setConnection(null);
            }
            try {
                 SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
                connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                        "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

                // Set the status to available
                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                connection.sendPacket(presence);
                setConnection(connection);

                Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "--------------------------------------");
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "User: " + entry.getUser());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Name: " + entry.getName());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Type: " + entry.getType());
                    Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry
                            .getUser());

                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "
                            + entryPresence.getStatus());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: "
                            + entryPresence.getType());
                    Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                    if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : "
                            + entryPresence);

                }
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                        + USERNAME);
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                setConnection(null);
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    t.start();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me solution to this problem ?

```
01-20 09:53:35.977: E/XMPPChatDemoActivity(3484): Failed to connect to talk.google.com
01-20 09:53:35.977: E/XMPPChatDemoActivity(3484): XMPPError connecting to talk.google.com:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to talk.google.com:5222.
01-20 09:53:35.977: E/XMPPChatDemoActivity(3484):   -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to talk.google.com/74.125.135.125 (port 5222): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
01-20 09:53:35.977: W/dalvikvm(3484): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-20 09:53:36.047: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-114
01-20 09:53:36.047: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:217)
01-20 09:53:36.047: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:353)
01-20 09:53:36.047: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.demo.xmppchat.XMPPChatDemoActivity$3.run(XMPPChatDemoActivity.java:162)
01-20 09:53:36.047: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: I have added internet permissions in manifest but still I am not able to connect to server

Comment: the 502 error not because of the problem from mobile side. But from server side. Please check the server if it is working properly or not. Server encountered some problem or it is down.

Comment: Did that suggestion helped?

Comment: @user1728071 yes it helped me. Actually I tried this code from office and here access is denied for gmail may be thats why I was getting this error I will try it from home

Comment: @poojagupta did you get a solution to this problem ?? I'm facing the same issue